# How could I pack a rack web-application includes infinite loop

Tags: ruby, rake

I want to pack a rack web-application in order to distribute it, In which a infinite loop resides. So it won't stop until my ctrl-c. But it seems ocra will only pack it when it ends 'naturally', and ctrl-c  stopped the process.

have been tring use `exit` or `abort` in `call`method of object being passed to `rake`. after which the whole process do not end, some trace info appears though.

it is possible to invoke `rake.run` in a thread, and end application after given time. But I do not want to distribute a suicide version. so is there some more eligible and controllable way to normally end it ?

not sure if this is a insane question, but thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the OCRA docu](http://ocra.rubyforge.org/), OCRA sets an environment variable `OCRA_EXECUTABLE` when being run.

So you could check for that environment var in your code and break the loop if OCRA is running, e.g.:

```
 while true
   break if ENV.has_key? 'OCRA_EXECUTABLE'
   ...
 end
```

Comment: wow this is more than helpful. thanks!
I have been thinking about some weird way to end it insynchronally with a special HTTP request..

Comment: @Jokester, I just found your old question. I'm having the same problem now, I start my server with `Rack::Server.start options`, but I'm not sure how checking that environment variable can help me with this problem.

Comment: Hello @Sven. Are you trying to pack it with OCRA as well? I cannot recall exactly, but I guess we can use that env variable to break the loop only when packing. It will still be an infinite loop when running as `.exe`.

Comment: @Jokester I [just asked another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221899/ocra-missing-submodules-of-libraries-if-rack-grape-api-endpoints-arent-called) that now shows how I'm skipping the call to start the server, which brings me other problems.. Do you remember if there were similar problems when you did this?

Comment: @Sven see if my answer in that question helps.