# OCRA missing submodules of libraries if rack/grape api endpoints aren't called

Tags: ruby, rack, ocra

I'm trying to pack my REST app into into an executable with [OCRA](http://ocra.rubyforge.org/). I have a few gems required in my script:

```
require 'rack'
require 'rack/server'
require 'grape'
require 'grape-entity'
require 'rubygems'
```

I skip starting the server with this:

```
if not defined?(Ocra)
    Rack::Server.start options
end
```

When I try to run my server.exe:

```
Temp/../server.rb:221:in `default_middleware_by_environment': 
cannot load such file -- rack/content_length (LoadError)
```

Which means that it doesn't detect submodules of rack that exist, but aren't used and therefore not included. If I add a `require 'rack/content_length' it continues with` cannot load such file -- rack/chunkedEven` and so on.

When I interrupted my server by hand before I also had to call a few api endpoints to have everything included.

I think my options are either:

- Tell OCRA to include all the submodules of rack and grape, but compiling that list is a bit time consuming and would increase the file size

  I already tried `ocra server.rb --gem-full=rack --gem-full=grape`, which get my server started, but when calling the API 'rack/mount/strexp' is missing again..
- Calling the API within my script, but I couldn't figure out how to do that. I can't add a block to `Rack::Server.start options` and it does only continue when I interrupt the server.

Any ideas to implement either option, or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

If we run the rack app with a rack handler (webrick / thin / else), we can shutdown the server in another thread so that ocra can finish packing (not sure how to do same thing with `Rack::Server`).

```
app     = Rack::Directory.new ENV['HOME'] # a sample app
handler = Rack::Handler.pick %w/ thin webrick /
handler.run app do |server|
  # handler.run yields a server object,
  # which we shutdown when ocra is packing
  if ocra_is_packing # replace with proper condition
    Thread.new { sleep 10; server.shutdown }
  end
end
```

You may have to do something else (access the server etc.) to have ocra pack appropriate dependencies.